# How to check local and global scope in Python and override variables in a class?

Tags: python

I am learning Python scope and unable to understand with a program, here is my code

```
a = "bat"
class Test():
    a = "ball"    
    b = [a for i in range(2)]
    e = lambda: a
    @staticmethod
    def f():
        return a
        
    g = lambda a=a: a
    d = a

print(Test.b)  # prints ["bat","bat"]
print(Test.e()) # prints bat
print(Test.f()) # prints bat
print(Test.g()) # prints ball
print(Test.d)  # prints ball
```

Here I have declared variable a="bat" outside the class and then I declared variable a="ball" inside class which is local to it. When I access the local a="ball" inside the class how is it returning the variable a="bat" declared outside the class in first 3 prints & not in the last 2 prints?

Answer (score 1):

When a class is created, there is a new namespace for the class. `a` (the second one), `b`, `e`, `f`,`g` and `d` are all created in the class namespace. Any time you try to access `a` from within that same namespace, it gets the inner `"ball"` value, but for any new scope it will first try to find `a` in its local namespace, then skip the class namespace and use the global namespace.

For `d = a`, it is inside the class namespace so is `"ball"`.
For `g = lambda a=a: a`, when resolving the `a` inside the lambda the function, it finds the `a` in the local namespace which was set to a default value when in the class namespace, so it resolves to `"ball"`.

For all others, they try to access `a` from a local namespace, but do not find it, so check the global namespace and find it there.

Comment: Please explain why `b = [a for i in range(2)]` will take global a and not local a. There is a local namespace a declared right before b!

Comment: @Javin there is a local namespace, but no `a` defined in the local namespace, so it looks in the global namespace. (If there weren't a local namespace it would have used the class namespace.)

Comment: @Javin It looks like I failed to mention that list comprehensions have their own local scope, similarly to function definitions. This must happen because `[a for i in range(2)]` introduces the local variable `i` which is not visible in the outer scope.